# Accessing link in email body using gmail API

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am using gmail api and python to access my gmail inbox. My email is stored in `mime_msg`. I want to access `'http://example.com/newpasswordid=exampleid12345'` as seen below. How can I do that?

```
msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(full_message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)
print(mime_msg)
```

```
<a href =3D 'http://example.com/newpasswordid=exampleid12345'>Link1</a><br><br>.</td></tr>

<tr><td><i>=A92020 For more info please visit=
 <a href=3D" https://example2.com/">Link2</a=></i></td></tr>
```

Comment: Do you just have a string containing the HTML you show, and you want to extract the first URL from the string?

Comment: @Steve I want to extract 'http://example.com/newpasswordid=exampleid12345' from the variable mime_msg

Comment: So like my answer?  Do you really not want the `http://` part? Tell me in comments on the answer if you are looking for something different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have that text in the string `mime_msg`, and you just want to extract the URL, that's pretty simple.  If you know your format is always going to be such that you want what's in the first pair of single quotes, you can use this code:

```
import re

mime_msg = """
<a href =3D 'http://example.com/newpasswordid=exampleid12345'>Link1</a><br><br>.</td></tr>

<tr><td><i>=A92020 For more info please visit=
 <a href=3D" https://example2.com/">Link2</a=></i></td></tr>
 """

exp = re.compile(r"'(.*?)'")
mime_msg = re.sub(r"[\n\r]+", '', mime_msg)
m = exp.search(mime_msg)
print(m.group(1))
```

Result:

```
http://example.com/newpasswordid=exampleid12345
```

If you wanted to be able to deal with more complex mail bodies, you could make the regular expression more complex.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The variable mime_msg contains my email body. I've tried your example above, and I get the error 

  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.py", line 66, in main
    print(m.group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: That means the regular expression isn't matching the text.  But it does for me.  I wonder what happened?  Something probably changed in the copy/paste.  Did the quotes maybe change to "funny quotes"?  Are you printing the text just before my code, like you show in your example?  You should do that to make sure your message is really there.

Comment: I checked and it is the same as how you did it other than m = exp.search(str(mime_msg)). Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: You could try a different expression: `exp = re.compile(r"(http.*?).>")`

Comment: I've tried the new expression, and it returns me the second link.

Comment: That's quite bizarre.  I can't think what is happening.  That expression says to grab the first `http` and everything after it up to a `>`.  That should match the first URL as well as the second, and so should return the first one since it will match that one first.

Comment: I think the issue could be because the first link is not recognized as a url

Comment: all that matters is that it matches what I said...`http` + some number of chars + `>`.  Doesn't the first one match that pattern too from what you can see?

Comment: Strange.  This one line prints the URL for me as well: `print(mime_msg.split("'")[1])`

Comment: It can't recognize the first URL because in the email body, the url is split into 2 lines. So instead of http://example.com/newpasswordid=exampleid12345, it is http://example.com/newpasswordi and d=exampleid12345 on another line. Thanks anyway for your response!

Comment: Oh.  Well, we can deal with that! - why didn't that show up in your question?

Comment: Sorry, had to change up the url and forgot about it

Comment: I just added a line of code to the answer.  Try that version.

Comment: Cool!  Learn all about regular expressions when you can.  You can do amazing things with them.